# Evaluating $\int \frac{1}{{x^4+1}} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, partial-fractions

I am trying to evaluate the integral

$$\int \frac{1}{1+x^4} \mathrm dx.$$

The integrand $\frac{1}{1+x^4}$ is a rational function (quotient of two polynomials), so I could solve the integral if I can find the partial fraction of $\frac{1}{1+x^4}$. But I failed to factorize $1+x^4$.

Any other methods are also wellcome.

Comment: I suppose it's been long enough (6 to 7 weeks). At this [Math Forum archived post](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=6868513) you'll find 3 .pdf files giving extremely detailed evaluations of the antiderivative of $\frac{1}{x^n + 1}$ for $n=4,\;5,$ and $6.$

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Without using fractional decomposition:
$$\begin{align}\int\dfrac{1}{x^4+1}~dx&=\dfrac{1}{2}\int\dfrac{2}{x^4+1}~dx
\\&=\dfrac{1}{2}\int\dfrac{(x^2+1)-(x^2-1)}{x^4+1}~dx
\\&=\dfrac{1}{2}\int\dfrac{x^2+1}{x^4+1}~dx-\dfrac{1}{2}\int\dfrac{x^2-1}{x^4+1}~dx
\\&=\dfrac{1}{2}\int\dfrac{1+\dfrac{1}{x^2}}{x^2+\dfrac{1}{x^2}}~dx-\dfrac{1}{2}\int\dfrac{1-\dfrac{1}{x^2}}{x^2+\dfrac{1}{x^2}}~dx
\\&=\dfrac{1}{2}\left(\int\dfrac{1+\dfrac{1}{x^2}}{\left(x-\dfrac{1}{x}\right)^2+2}~dx-\int\dfrac{1-\dfrac{1}{x^2}}{\left(x+\dfrac{1}{x}\right)^2-2}~dx\right)
\\&=\dfrac{1}{2}\left(\int\dfrac{d\left(x-\dfrac{1}{x}\right)}{\left(x-\dfrac{1}{x}\right)^2+2}-\int\dfrac{d\left(x+\dfrac{1}{x}\right)}{\left(x+\dfrac{1}{x}\right)^2-2}\right)\end{align}$$

So, finally solution is $$\int\dfrac{1}{x^4+1}~dx=\dfrac{1}{4\sqrt2}\left(2\arctan\left(\dfrac{x^2-1}{\sqrt2x}\right)+\log\left(\dfrac{x^2+\sqrt2x+1}{x^2-\sqrt2x+1}\right)\right)+C$$

Comment: This is really difficult . You are genius .

Answer (score 11):

**Hint:**
$$x^4+1=(x^2-\sqrt{2}x+1)(x^2+\sqrt{2}x+1) \tag{1}$$
You can integrate using partial fraction decomposition. Since
$$x^4+1=(x^2-\sqrt{2}x+1)(x^2+\sqrt{2}x+1),$$
then
$$\frac{1}{x^4+1}=\frac{Ax+B}{x^2-\sqrt{2}x+1}+\frac{Cx+D}{x^2+\sqrt{2}x+1}=\frac{(Ax+B)(x^2+\sqrt{2}x+1)+(Cx+D)(x^2-\sqrt{2}x+1)}{(x^2-\sqrt{2}x+1)(x^2+\sqrt{2}x+1)} = \\
= \frac{x^3(A+C)+x^2(A\sqrt{2}+B+D-C\sqrt{2})+x(B\sqrt{2}-D\sqrt{2})+B+D}{(x^2-\sqrt{2}x+1)(x^2+\sqrt{2}x+1)}$$
$$\begin{cases}
A+C=0;\\
B+D+\sqrt{2}(A-C)=0; \\
B-D=0; \\
B+D=1.
\end{cases}$$

$$
A=-C=-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}; \\
B=D=\frac{1}{2}$$

$$
\frac{1}{x^4+1}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\left(\dfrac{-x+\sqrt{2}}{x^2-\sqrt{2}x+1}+ \dfrac{x+\sqrt{2}}{x^2+\sqrt{2}x+1} \right).
$$

**Added**
Decomposition (1) can be done using one of the following ways:

1. Completion to the full square 
   $$x^4+1=x^4 +2x^2+1 -2x^2=(x^2+1)^2-\left(\sqrt{2}x\right)^2 = \\ =\big(x^2-\sqrt{2}x +1 \big)\big( x^2+\sqrt{2}x +1 \big).$$
2. Let $\omega_i, \ i\in\{1,\, 2,\,3,\,4\}   $ are roots of the equation $x^4+1=0$ over $\mathbb{C}:$ $\omega_1=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(1-i), \ \omega_2=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(1+i) \ \omega_3=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(-1+i), \ \omega_4=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(-1-i). $ Then use the decomposition into prime factors and multiply pairwise complex conjugate:
   $x^4+1= \left( x-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(1-i) \right)\left( x-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(1+i) \right)\left( x-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(-1+i) \right)\left( x-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(-1-i) \right) = \\ =\big(x^2-\sqrt{2}x +1 \big)\big( x^2+\sqrt{2}x +1 \big).$

Comment: Its too difficult to calculate yet

Comment: He said "FULL ANSWER"!

Comment: Why is that too difficult? Well, you could do $$\int\frac1{x^4+4}\,dx$$ first using the factorization coming from $$x^4+4=(x^4+4x^2+4)-4x^2=\cdots$$ and then do a linear substitution to get back to your integral.

Comment: We won't do your homework - we try to teach you to do it yourself.

Comment: @M.Strochyk How did you *compute* $x^4+1$ to be equal to $(x^2-\sqrt{2}x +1)(x^2+\sqrt{2}x+1)$? Is there a *general method* for doing that?

Comment: @Mr Reality: I added decomposition of $x^4+1$ into factors to my answer.

Comment: @M.Strochyk thanks for doing that but I think I should have stated myself more clearly - why did you decide to add and subtract $2x^2$ specifically? Why not something else? I mean did you know that you'll be able to factorize  the polynomial thus?

Comment: @MrReality No, there is no general method to factorise a polynomial of > degree 4. The equations for $3,4$ are just impractical. So in summary there is no general way to factorise any polynomial above degree 2.

Comment: @A---B, why are the equations for $3,4$ *impractical*? Do you mean it is *Always* *easier* to find some term to add/subtract to the given polynomial for factorizing it (like in the above example)?

Comment: @MrReality Just take a look at [cubic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6L8y.png) and [quartic](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/99/Quartic_Formula.svg) formula, you'll know what I am talking about.  It is not easier to factorise either, try to factorise $x^4 + x + 1 = 0$.

Comment: @A---B, wow, that really is cumbersome. But then what about the second part of my question - is it always possible to solve, say, a cubic or a quartic equation by adding & subtracting some term/s to the given polynomial?

Comment: @MrReality Yes it is always possible but not feasible to factorise any polynomial.  Try $x^4 + x + 1= 0$ for instance.

Comment: @A---B, I couldn't figure out how to do that. But I think that's because I don't know how we *select* the term that'd help us to factorize the polynomial- do we try to recall some identitiy or rule or something else?

Comment: @MrReality No surprise you couldn't figure it out. [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E4+%2B+x+%2B+1+%3D+0) shows that it is impossible for anyone. I gave that example to show you that it is not feasible to factorise every polynomial but it is certainly possible.

Answer (score 5):

$$I =\int \frac{1}{{x^4+1}} dx$$

If we add and subtract $2x^2$ to $x^4 + 1$, we get:
$$\int \frac{1}{{x^4 + 2x^2 + 1 - 2x^2}}$$

We know $x^4 + 2x^2 + 1 = (x^2 + 1)^2$

$$\int \frac{1}{{(x^2 + 1)^2 - 2x^2}}$$

We know $a^2 - b^2 = (a - b)(a + b)$

Hence, $(x^2 + 1)^2 - 2x^2 = (x^2 + 1 - \sqrt{2}x)(x^2 + 1 + \sqrt{2}x)$

$$\int \frac{1}{{(x^2-\sqrt{2}x+1)(x^2+\sqrt{2}x+1)}}$$

Now using partial fraction decomposition:

$$\frac{1}{(x^2-\sqrt{2}x+1)(x^2+\sqrt{2}x+1)} = \frac{Ax + B}{x^2-\sqrt{2}x+1} + \frac{Cx + D}{x^2+\sqrt{2}x+1}$$

After you have found A, B, C and D, its just a basic $\frac{linear}{quadratic}$ type integral.

Comment: Is there a general method for factorizing *stuff* like $x^4+1$?

Answer (score 1):

The indefinite integral is a rational fraction and is typically solved using partial fractions decomposition.

You first factor the denominator $x^4+1$, which has four complex roots, the fourth roots of minus one, let $\omega_0$, $\omega_1$, $\omega_2$, and $\omega_3$. Then you decompose

$$\frac1{x^4+1}=\frac a{x-\omega_0}+\frac b{x-\omega_1}+\frac c{x-\omega_2}+\frac d{x-\omega_3}$$

The unknown coefficients are found by multiplying by one of the denominators and taking the limit to the root:

$$a=\lim_{x\to\omega_0}\frac{x-\omega_0}{x^4+1}=\frac1{4\omega_0^3},$$
and similarly for the other terms.

Then, a single term is integrated with a complex logarithm
$$\int\frac{dx}{x-\omega}=\ln(x-\omega)=\ln|x-\omega|+i\angle(x-\omega).$$

Here we have $\omega_0=\dfrac{1+i}{\sqrt2}$, hence

$$\ln\sqrt{(x-\frac1{\sqrt2})^2+(\frac1{\sqrt2})^2}-i\arctan\frac{\frac1{\sqrt2}}{x-\frac1{\sqrt2}}\\
=\frac12\ln(x^2-\sqrt2x+1)-i\frac\pi2+i\arctan(\sqrt2x-1).$$

Repeat for the four terms (there is a lot of symmetry) and form the linear combination.

Comment: I could not understand the answer after Step 1 .