# Integrate rational function $\frac{x^2}{1+x^4}$

Tags: calculus, integration

Integrate $$\int\frac{x^2dx}{1+x^4}$$
I've factored the denominator to $(x^2-\sqrt{2}x+1)(x^2+\sqrt{2}x+1)$ and got stuck.

Comment: it is good starting point,i will upload picture

Comment: ok i have deleted my answer.first of   all  when i am posting  answer  from wolfram alpha,because it requires  some autoriation like facebook or  registration,that why  maybe OP is not registered on facebook,he should  worry about this.but no problem  .i have deleted my asnwer

Answer (score 6):

Or, use $$\frac{x^2}{1+x^4}=\frac{1}{2} \frac{2x^2}{1+x^4}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x^2-1}{1+x^4}+\frac{x^2+1}{1+x^4}\right)$$ and [this idea](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/333611/evaluating-int-frac1x41-dx/333637#333637).

Answer (score 3):

The next step is to perform a partial fraction decomposition:
$$
   \frac{x^2}{(x^2-\sqrt{2}x+1)(x^2+\sqrt{2}x+1)} = \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{2}} \frac{x}{x^2-\sqrt{2}x+1} - \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{2}} \frac{x}{x^2+\sqrt{2}x+1}
$$
And the than use the table anti-derivative for $\int \frac{x}{x^2 + a x+b} \mathrm{d}x$.