# Primitive with Cebisev's subtitution

Tags: calculus, integration

Can somebody give me some tips on how to determine the primitive of $\frac{x^{23}}{x^{32}+1} dx$, please?

Sorry for not using latex but I'm writing on the phone and I can't see the editor. I tried using Cebisev's subtitution and I get $t=x^{17/2}$ and I don't know what to do after. Can somebody help me please? And sorry for the bad writing.

Comment: I suggest substituting $t=x^8$ instead, then use [Integrate rational function $\frac{x^2}{1+x^4}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/349424/integrate-rational-function-fracx21x4).