# Help with $\int\frac{1}{1+x^8}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I'm not sure how to proceed. I tried factoring like you do to evaluate $\int\frac{1}{1+x^4}dx$, and since it came out nasty I checked out WolframAlpha to see if I was on the right track. In fact, Wolfram doesn't have a step-by-step solution for the integral in question, but the primitive is full of trig expressions like $\csc\frac{\pi}{8}$ and I'm not sure where these would come from.

Comment: I'm not an integration guru *at all*. Is the following transformation of any use? \begin{align*}
\int \frac{1}{1+x^8}\,dx &= \int \biggl( 1-\frac{x^8}{1+x^8} \biggr)\,dx \\
&=x-\int \frac{x^8}{1+x^8} \,dx
\end{align*}

Comment: Are you familiar with complex partial fractions?

Comment: Complex partial fractions as in difficult/complicated, or as in complex valued? The first yes, the second no.

Answer (score 13):

You have a vile lecturer. I had to find $\displaystyle \int \dfrac{1}{1+x^4}dx$ when I took my analysis II course and I actually wrote on my notes: you just don't wish this antiderivative on anyone. It took me one page and a half (A4) to find this antiderivative and I didn't prove all the details. Yours is much more troublesome.

**Hint:** For all $x\in \Bbb R$, the following equality holds:$$1+x^8=\left(x^2+\left(\sqrt{2-\sqrt 2}\right)x+1\right)\left(x^2-\left(\sqrt{2-\sqrt 2}\right)x+1\right)\\\left(x^2+\left(\sqrt{2+\sqrt 2}\right)x+1\right)\left(x^2-\left(\sqrt{2+\sqrt 2}\right)x+1\right).$$

You can then use partial fractions and find the antiderivatives.

[Here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2Bx%5E8%3D%5Cleft%28x%5E2%2B%28%5Csqrt%7B2-%5Csqrt+2%7D%29x%2B1%5Cright%29%5Cleft%28x%5E2-%28%5Csqrt%7B2-%5Csqrt+2%7D%29x%2B1%5Cright%29%5Cleft%28x%5E2%2B%28%5Csqrt%7B2%2B%5Csqrt+2%7D%29x%2B1%5Cright%29%5Cleft%28x%5E2-%28%5Csqrt%7B2%2B%5Csqrt+2%7D%29x%2B1%5Cright%29)'s the Wolfram Alpha confirmation of the above equality.

Comment: The real factorization of $1+x^4$ depends on the (should be) well-known $x^4+4=(x^2-2x+2)(x^2+2x+2)$, but $1+x^8$ looks considerably more recherché.

Comment: @Lubin Well, the factorization is easy to find, just a few calculations. I guess the important part is realizing that every real polynomial with degree greater than $2$ is reducible over $\Bbb R$.

Comment: So I suppose the $\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}$ and $\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}$ expressions are the values of the trig functions at $\frac{\pi}{8}$ , then, which explains the WolframAlpha output.

Comment: @user86859 Close. Note that those numbers are greater than $1$. However $\cos (\pi /8)=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2+\sqrt 2}$ and $\sin (\pi /8)=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2-\sqrt 2}$ .

Comment: $\int\frac{1}{1+x^4}~dx$ has this simpler approach avoiding fully partial fraction: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/333611

Answer (score 6):

If we write
$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
x^{8}+1 &=&(x^{4}+px^{2}+1)(x^{4}-px^{2}+1)=x^{8}+\left( 2-p^{2}\right)
x^{4}+1 \\
&\Rightarrow &2-p^{2}=0\Leftrightarrow p=\pm \sqrt{2},
\end{eqnarray*}
$$
we get
$$
\begin{equation*}
x^{8}+1=\left( x^{4}+\sqrt{2}x^{2}+1\right) \left( x^{4}-\sqrt{2}
x^{2}+1\right) .
\end{equation*}
$$
Similarly,
$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
x^{4}+\sqrt{2}x^{2}+1 &=&(x^{2}+qx+1)(x^{2}-qx+1)=x^{4}+\left(
2-q^{2}\right) x^{2}+1 \\
&\Rightarrow &2-q^{2}=\sqrt{2}\Leftrightarrow q=\pm \sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}, \\
x^{4}+\sqrt{2}x^{2}+1 &=&(x^{2}+\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}x+1)(x^{2}-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}
x+1),
\end{eqnarray*}
$$
and
$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
x^{4}-\sqrt{2}x^{2}+1 &=&(x^{2}+rx+1)(x^{2}-rx+1)=x^{4}+\left(
2-r^{2}\right) x^{2}+1 \\
&\Rightarrow &2-r^{2}=-\sqrt{2}\Leftrightarrow r=\pm \sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}, \\
x^{4}-\sqrt{2}x^{2}+1 &=&(x^{2}+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}x+1)(x^{2}-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}
x+1).
\end{eqnarray*}
$$
Consequently,
$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
x^{8}+1 &=&(x^{2}+\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}x+1)(x^{2}-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}x+1) \\
&&\times (x^{2}+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}x+1)(x^{2}-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}x+1).
\end{eqnarray*}
$$
Since the expansion of the integrand into partial fractions yields
$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{1}{x^{8}+1} &=&\frac{1}{8}\frac{\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}x+2}{x^{2}+\sqrt{2-
\sqrt{2}}x+1}+\frac{1}{8}\frac{-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}x+2}{x^{2}-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}
x+1} \\ && \\
&&+\frac{1}{8}\frac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}x+2}{x^{2}+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}x+1}+\frac{1
}{8}\frac{-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}x+2}{x^{2}-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}x+1},
\end{eqnarray*}
$$
we have
$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
I &=&\int \frac{dx}{x^{8}+1}=I_{1}+I_{2}+I_{3}+I_{4} \\ && \\
&=&\frac{1}{8}\int \frac{\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}x+2}{x^{2}+\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}x+1}dx+
\frac{1}{8}\int \frac{-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}x+2}{x^{2}-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}x+1}dx \\ && \\
&&+\frac{1}{8}\int \frac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}x+2}{x^{2}+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}x+1}dx+
\frac{1}{8}\int \frac{-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}x+2}{x^{2}-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}x+1}dx.
\end{eqnarray*}
$$
These four integrals are all of the form $\int \frac{Ax+B}{x^{2}+bx+1}dx$. So we need to evaluate  $\int \frac{1}{x^{2}+bx+1}dx$ and $\int \frac{x\,dx}{ax^{2}+bx+c}$. The first integral is computable by completing the
square in the denominator and making a linear change of variables:

$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int \frac{dx}{ax^{2}+bx+c} &=&\frac{1}{a}\int \frac{dx}{x^{2}+\frac{b}{a}x+
\frac{c}{a}},\qquad\qquad 4ac-b^{2}>0 \\
&=&\frac{1}{a}\int \frac{dx}{\left( x-\frac{-b}{2a}\right) ^{2}+\left( \frac{
\sqrt{4ac-b^{2}}}{2a}\right) ^{2}}, \\
&=&\frac{1}{a}\int \frac{dx}{\left( x-p\right) ^{2}+q^{2}},\quad p=\frac{-b}{
2a},q=\frac{\sqrt{4ac-b^{2}}}{2a},\quad x=p+qt \\
&=&\frac{1}{aq}\int \frac{1}{t^{2}+1}\,dt \\
&=&\frac{2}{\sqrt{4ac-b^{2}}}\int \frac{1}{t^{2}+1}\,dt \\
&=&\frac{2}{\sqrt{4ac-b^{2}}}\arctan t,\qquad t=\frac{x-p}{q}=\frac{2ax+b}{
\sqrt{4ac-b^{2}}} \\
&=&\frac{2}{\sqrt{4ac-b^{2}}}\arctan \frac{2ax+b}{\sqrt{4ac-b^{2}}}+C.\tag{1}
\end{eqnarray*}
$$

The second one is more straightforward
$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int \frac{x\,dx}{ax^{2}+bx+c} &=&\frac{1}{2a}\int \frac{2ax+b-b\,}{ax^{2}+bx+c}dx \\
&=&\frac{1}{2a}\int \frac{2ax+b}{ax^{2}+bx+c}dx-\frac{b}{2a}\int \frac{1}{ax^{2}+bx+c}dx \\
&=&\frac{1}{2a}\log \left(\left\vert ax^{2}+bx+c\right\vert\right) -\frac{b}{2a}\int \frac{dx}{ax^{2}+bx+c}.\tag{2}
\end{eqnarray*}
$$
For $a=c=1$ and $4-b^{2}>0$ we get from $(1)$ and $(2)$

\begin{eqnarray*}
\int \frac{Ax+B}{x^{2}+bx+1}dx &=&A\int \frac{x\,dx}{x^{2}+bx+1}+B\int \frac{
dx}{x^{2}+bx+1} \\
&=&\frac{2B-Ab}{\sqrt{4-b^{2}}}\arctan \frac{2x+b}{\sqrt{4-b^{2}}}+\frac{A}{2
}\log \left( \left\vert x^{2}+bx+1\right\vert \right) +C.\tag{3}
\end{eqnarray*}

E.g. the first integral evaluates as
\begin{eqnarray*}
I_{1} &=&\frac{1}{8}\int \frac{\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}x+2}{x^{2}+\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}
x+1}dx \\
&=&\frac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}{8}\arctan \frac{2x+\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}}{\sqrt{2+
\sqrt{2}}}+\frac{\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}}{16}\log \left( x^{2}+\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}
x+1\right) +C.
\end{eqnarray*}

ADDED. The entry 2.142 of *Table of Integrals Series and Products* by Gradshteyn and
Ryzhik gives the family of integrals $\int \frac{dx}{1+x^{n}}$ for $n\in 
\mathbb{N}$. From the given formula the particular case for $n=2p=8$ yields

\begin{eqnarray*}
\int \frac{dx}{1+x^{8}} &=&-\frac{1}{8}\sum_{k=0}^{3}\left( \log \left(
x^{2}-2x\cos \left( \frac{\left( 2k+1\right) \pi }{8}\right) +1\right)
\right) \times \cos \left( \frac{\left( 2k+1\right) \pi }{8}\right)  \\
&&+\frac{1}{4}\sum_{k=0}^{3}\left( \arctan \left( \frac{x\sin \frac{\left(
2k+1\right) \pi }{8}}{1-x\cos \frac{\left( 2k+1\right) \pi }{8}}\right)
\right) \times \sin \left( \frac{\left( 2k+1\right) \pi }{8}\right) +C.
\end{eqnarray*}

ADDED 2. 
The values of $\sin \left( \frac{\left( 2k+1\right) \pi }{8}\right) $ and $\cos \left( \frac{\left( 2k+1\right) \pi }{8}\right) $ are quadratic
irrationals:
$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sin \frac{\pi }{8} &=&\sin \frac{7\pi }{8}=\cos \frac{3\pi }{8}=\frac{1}{2}
\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}, \\
&& \\
\sin \frac{3\pi }{8} &=&\sin \frac{5\pi }{8}=\cos \frac{\pi }{8}=\frac{1}{2}
\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}, \\
&& \\
\cos \frac{5\pi }{8} &=&\cos \frac{7\pi }{8}=-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}.
\end{eqnarray*}
$$

Answer (score 5):

The roots of $1+x^8$ are 16-th roots of unity; they are $\zeta^{1+2k}$ where $\zeta$ is a primitive 16-th root of unity, and $k$ goes from $0$ to $7$.

They are all distinct, so we can use the simple formula for partial fractions decomposition of $f(x)/g(x)$ that says the coefficient on the $1/(x-a)$ term is $f(a)/g'(a)$.
Therefore,

$$ \frac{1}{1+x^8} = \sum_{k=0}^7 \frac{1}{8 (\zeta^{1+2k})^7} \cdot \frac{1}{x-\zeta^{1+2k}}
= \sum_{k=0}^7 \frac{1}{8 \zeta^{7-2k}} \cdot \frac{1}{x-\zeta^{1+2k}}
$$

It may be of use that the summands $k$ and $7-k$ are complex conjugate. If one is so inclined, one could add those terms together; the result should be a purely real function with a linear numerator and quadratic denominator, giving you the purely real partial fraction decomposition.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the best way to get around this kind of integrals is to factor the denominator as below $$x^{n}+1=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(x-\alpha^{2k+1}\right)$$ where $$\alpha=e^{i\frac{\pi}{n}}$$ is the primitive $n$ root of $-1$. Then we can find the partial fraction expansion of the integrand as $$\frac{1}{x^n+1}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{A_k}{x-\alpha^{2k+1}}$$ where $$A_k=\lim_{x\rightarrow \alpha^{2k+1}}\frac{x-\alpha^{2k+1}}{x^n+1}$$ Then the integral becomes $$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\int \frac{A_k}{x-\alpha^{2k+1}}dx$$ But now, there are many complex terms involved, we need to collect terms together to simplify them to real rational functions. This is not easy for any arbitrary $n$, but is plausible particularly if $n$ is of the form $2^k$ for some $k\in \mathbb{Z}^+$, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_rational_functions).

For the current problem, fortunately $n=8=2^3$, so this method works here.

Answer (score 1):

Decompose the integrand as

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{1+x^8}
&=\frac{2+\sqrt2}8 \left( \frac{1+x^2}{x^4+\sqrt2x^2+1}
+\frac{1-x^2}{x^4-\sqrt2x^2+1}   \right)\\
 &\hspace{5mm}+\frac{2-\sqrt2}8 \left( \frac{1+x^2}{x^4-\sqrt2x^2+1}
+\frac{1-x^2}{x^4+\sqrt2x^2+1}   \right)
\end{align}

and utilize the integrals

$$\begin{align}
I(a)&=\int\frac{1+x^2}{x^4+ax^2+1}dx 
=\frac1{\sqrt{2+a}}\tan^{-1}\frac{x^2-1}{x\sqrt{2+a}} \\
 J(a)&=\int\frac{1-x^2}{x^4+ax^2+1}dx 
=\frac1{\sqrt{2-a}}\coth^{-1}\frac{x^2+1}{x\sqrt{2-a}} \\
\end{align}$$

to obtain
\begin{align}
\int \frac{1}{1+x^8}dx
&= \frac{2+\sqrt2}8 \left[ I(\sqrt2)+ J(-\sqrt2)  \right]
+\frac{2-\sqrt2}8 \left[ I(-\sqrt2)+ J(\sqrt2)  \right]\\
& =\frac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt2}}8 \bigg( \tan^{-1}\frac{x^2-1}{x\sqrt{2+\sqrt2}}
+ \coth^{-1}\frac{x^2+1}{x\sqrt{2+\sqrt2}}\bigg)\\
&\hspace{5mm}+\frac{\sqrt{2-\sqrt2}}8 \bigg( \tan^{-1}\frac{x^2-1}{x\sqrt{2-\sqrt2}}
+ \coth^{-1}\frac{x^2+1}{x\sqrt{2-\sqrt2}}\bigg)\\
\end{align}