# How to compute $\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{dt}{1+t^4} = \frac{\pi}{2\sqrt 2}.$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

> How to compute
>
> $$\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{dt}{1+t^4} = \frac{\pi}{2\sqrt 2}.$$
>   I'm interested in more ways of computing this integral.

There is always the straight forward method to decompose into simple elements 
$\dfrac{1}{(1 + t^{4})}$ it works but it is tedious. If someone has a faster and clever method, I'm interested :)

**Update :**

- My quesion is *different* than [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/333611/evaluating-int-frac1x41-dx) because all the solution that state there is talk about the the straight forward method to decompose into simple elements $\dfrac{1}{(1 + t^{4})}$ as i said before i'm not intersted in that way

Comment: The residue theorem is useful for such integrals.

Comment: all the solution that state in ur link is about the straight forward method to decompose into simple elements  $\dfrac{1}{(1 + t^{4})}$

Comment: If you still consider those methods to be tedious then you should learn the residue theorem. I think the residue theorem is as simple as it gets

Comment: if you want to have even more fun then with the solutions below, substitute $x^2 \rightarrow t$ and integrate around a keyhole contour. But this is really using an big gun to crank a small nut..^^

Comment: @tired   yes of course :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is another method using purely clever substitutions. Note that

$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{1+x^4}
=
\int_{0}^\infty \frac{w^2}{1+w^4} \mathrm{d}w
$$

Where the last integral comes from the substitution $w \mapsto 1/x$. Addition now gives that
$$
\begin{align*}
\int_0^\infty \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{1+x^4}
& = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty \frac{1+x^2}{1+x^4}\mathrm{d}x \\
& = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty \frac{1+1/x^2}{x^2+1/x^2} \mathrm{d}x \\
& = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty \frac{(x-1/x)'}{(x-1/x)^2+2} \mathrm{d}x \\
& = \frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{u^2+2} 
  = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{1+y^2}
  = \frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{2}}
\end{align*}
$$
Where the substitutions $u \mapsto x - 1/x$ and $y \mapsto \sqrt{2} u$ were used.

Comment: How did you find the substitutions ? It's not the first time I see some very clever change of variables ! Is there a theory behind ?

Comment: Always ;) I wrote a few pages on it here http://folk.ntnu.no/oistes/Diverse/Integral/Integral%20Kokeboken.pdf. Look at 87-88. The idea to note is that x^2 + 1/x^2 can be factorized, and this shows up in many many integrals. These "tricks" are onyl tricks when you see them once, after that they are tools you can employ yourself on tricky integrals.

Comment: Thank you so much ! I don't read german but still this is readable :) Last question : do you think your paper cover the majority of the sustitutions techniques needed to compute nearly every computable integral ? (I mean it is a survey on the existing techniques ?).

Comment: Without starting a longer discussion on the topic, that is the goal a tleast. Oh and it is in norwegian, not german however the languages share many similarities ;) Google translate should do the trick, however mathematics is the same in any language.

Comment: Really Clever and Interesting.

Answer (score 4):

Notice first that
$$
\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{1+t^4}=\frac12\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{1}{1+t^4}\,dt.
$$
Applying the Residue Theorem to the function $f: \mathbb{C}\setminus\{\pm e^{\pm i\frac\pi4}\} \to \mathbb{C}, z\mapsto \frac{1}{1+z^4}$, we have, for $R>1$:
$$
\int_{-R}^Rf(t)\,dt=\frac{2\pi i}{4}\left(-e^{i\frac\pi4}+e^{-i\frac\pi4}\right)-i\int_0^\pi\frac{Re^{i\theta}}{1+R^4e^{4i\theta}}\,d\theta.
$$
Since
$$
\lim_{R\to\infty}\left|\int_0^\pi\frac{Re^{i\theta}}{1+R^4e^{4i\theta}}\,d\theta\right|\le \lim_{R\to\infty}\int_0^\pi\frac{R}{R^4-1}=\lim_{R\to\infty}\frac{\pi R}{R^4-1}=0,
$$
it follows that
$$
\lim_{R\to \infty}\int_{-R}^Rf(t)\,dt=\frac{2\pi i}{4}\left(-e^{i\frac\pi4}+e^{-i\frac\pi4}\right)=\pi\sin\left(\frac\pi4\right)=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}.
$$
Hence
$$
\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{1+t^4}\,dt=\lim_{R\to\infty}\frac12\int_{-R}^R f(t)\,dt=\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{2}}.
$$

Answer (score 4):

$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dt}{1+t^4} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dt}{1+4t^4}\tag{1} $$
and:
$$ 1+4t^4 = (1+4t^2+4t^4)-(2t)^2 = (2t^2+2t+1)(2t^2-2t+1)\tag{2} $$
from which:
$$ \frac{1}{1+4t^4} = \frac{1-t}{2-4t+4t^2}+\frac{1+t}{2+4t+4t^2}\tag{3} $$
and:
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dt}{1+4t^4} = 2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1-t}{2-4t+4t^2}\,dt = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{2t}{2-4t+4t^2}\,dt \tag{4}$$
can be explicitly computed in terms of $\arctan(1-2t)$ and $\log(1-2t+2t^2)$.

Since $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{2t}{2-4t+4t^2}\,dt=\frac{\pi}{4}$, it follows that:
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{dt}{1+t^4} = \color{red}{\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}}.\tag{5}$$

Comment: how do you get your first step?

Comment: @manga_lovers: by using the substitution $t=u\sqrt{2}$.

Answer (score 3):

One may recall that the celebrated $\Gamma$ function may be defined by

> $$
> \Gamma(\alpha)=\int_0^\infty u^{\alpha-1} e^{-u}\:{\rm{d}}u, \quad \alpha>0,
> $$

giving
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x^4+1} \:{\rm{d}}x&=\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty e^{-(x^4+1)t} \:{\rm{d}}t\:{\rm{d}}x
\\&=\int_0^\infty e^{-t}\int_0^\infty e^{-x^4 t} \:{\rm{d}}t\:{\rm{d}}x
\\&=\int_0^\infty e^{-t}\left(\int_0^\infty e^{-x^4 t}\:{\rm{d}}x\right)\:{\rm{d}}t
\\&=\frac14\int_0^\infty t^{-\frac14}e^{-t}\left(\int_0^\infty u^{\frac14-1} e^{-u}{\rm{d}}u\right)\:{\rm{d}}t
\\&=\frac14 \Gamma\left(1-\frac14\right)\Gamma\left(\frac14\right)
\\&=\frac{\pi}{4\sin \frac{\pi}{4}}
\\&=\color{red}{\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{2}}}.
\end{align}
$$