# Calculation of $\int \frac{1}{x^4+1}$

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm trying to solve this integral in terms of elementary functions but my result does not seem to match up with Sage's or WolframAlpha's.

$$\int \frac{1}{x^4+1} = \frac{x}{1+x^4}+\int \frac{4x^4}{(1+x^4)^2}$$

Where:

$$4\int \frac{x^4}{(1+x^4)^2} = 4\int \frac{u-1}{u^2} = 4\log u + \frac{4}{u}$$

So the original integral is

$$\int \frac{1}{x^4+1} = \frac{x}{1+x^4} + 4\log (1+x^4) + \frac{4}{1+x^4}$$

Where did I go wrong here? Thanks.

Comment: You applied a naive change of variable. If we set $u=x^4$, then $du$ is affected, in particular $du = 4x^3 dx$.

Comment: The trick is just to exploit the Sophie Germain identity $$z^4+4 = (z^2-2z+2)(z^2+2z+2)$$ and partial fraction decomposition.

Comment: Thanks @JackD'Aurizio. You're right.

Comment: This has been asked so many times. Do check before posting. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/333611/evaluating-int-frac1x41-dx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint
$$x^4+1=(x^2+1)^2-2x^2=(x^2+1-\sqrt{2}x)(x^2+1+\sqrt{2}x)$$

Answer (score 1):

$$I=\frac12\int\frac {\frac{2}{x^2}}{x^2+\frac {1}{x^2}} $$
$$I=\frac12\int\frac{1+\frac {1}{x^2}}{(x-\frac {1}{x})^2+2}{dx}-\frac12\int\frac{1-\frac {1}{x^2}}{(x+\frac {1}{x})^2-2}{dx}$$